# Program crashes after using "delete" on temp pointer, even if new and delete lines are the only ones left?

Tags: c++, pointers, memory, dynamic

So I'm creating a doubly linked list class and use a temp node to insert new values and whatnot. So I have a Node struct:

```
template <typename T>
struct Node
{
    // Data in this node
    T mData;
    // Link to previous node
    Node* mPrev;
    // Link to next node
    Node* mNext;
};
```

and I have the following member variables in the actual List class:

```
// Pointer to the head node
Node<T>* mHead;
// Pointer to the tail node
Node<T>* mTail;
// Pointer to current node
Node<T>* mCurr;
// Number of nodes currently in the list
unsigned mSize;
```

All this is kosher, given to me by my professor.

However, whenever I create a temp pointer to insert a new value, using the delete keyword crashes the program with an error "First-chance exception at ... Access Violation reading location...". Here is an example of the function I'm writing:

```
void insert_front(const T& value)
{
    Node<T>* temp = new Node<T>;

    temp->mData = value;
    temp->mPrev = nullptr;
    temp->mNext = mHead;

    if (mSize == 0)
    {
        mTail = temp;
        mHead = temp;
    }
    else
    {
        mHead->mPrev = temp;
        mHead = temp;
    }
    mSize++;
    //delete temp;
}
```

Now aside from the obvious memory leak, this function works as it's supposed to. But when I add a delete ANYWHERE, the whole thing crashes. Even if I cut out EVERYTHING except for the new line and the delete line, everything crashes. The only other files in the program were created by my professor and have no errors. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please post a full example with the `delete` in. When you create nodes, you shouldn't delete them. You only delete them when you erase an element, or at list destruction.

Comment: Don't assume that code given by professors is without error.

Comment: @Neill Kirk I acknowledge that professors can mess up but none of my classmates have reported this issue and many of them have already submitted!

Comment: @vsoftco I will update my post to include it but I'm confused- I would not want to delete temp inside the scope of this function, but rather in the destructor? If so, how do I delete temp as it is not a global variable?

Comment: @AlexxMurphy They didn't report the issue because pointer mismanagement leads to *undefined behavior*.  There is no guarantee that a program will crash when these errors occur.  So it is highly likely, given that you wrote the same program, that your classmates are handing in programs with hidden bugs.

Comment: you won't have access to temp in destructor. however since it's a linked list, you will have access to head/root using which you can reach the nodes.

Comment: @AlexxMurphy Take a look e.g. [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=U-MfAoL6qjM).

Comment: Thank you, Nandu and vsoftco, both of your responses helped me identify the problem, which was that I don't need to delete temp, only head/tail etc. I fixed the memory leak and the program no longer crashes. Thanks ya'll!

Comment: Did you run the program in a debugger to find out which line causes the crash?

Comment: @AlexxMurphy You don't delete pointers, you delete *objects*. And you're not allowed to delete the object, then access it later, even if you used two different pointers to do that.

Comment: @immibus, I see thank you! It makes sense when you say it but I didn't relate it to what I was doing. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Were I betting man I'd wager that temp pointer is now an integral part of your list rather than a simple place holder.

```
if (mSize == 0)
{
    mTail = temp;
    mHead = temp;
}
else
{
    mHead->mPrev = temp;
    mHead = temp;
}
```

When you delete temp you are deleting whatever mTail and mHead or mHead->mPrev and mHead are pointing to.  When you try to access this deleted data you get undefined behavior which is usually a crash.